# Sitecore custom item validator

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I need to make a custom item validator that checks on workflow final state about the language versions that exist for the particular item. I know I am supposed to inherit Sitecore.Data.Validators.StandardValidator, or Sitecore.Data.Validators.ItemValidators.WorkFlowFinalStateValidator, but what are the methods that are available to me on this? Is there a way I can find this out?

**Update:** 
I created a custom validator using the StandardValidator class, and implementing the ValidatorResult method. I then registered this class in the system/settings/validation rules section. I then set the standard values fields for an item and this works in the regular Quick Bar validation rules, and the validation bar. I am able to see the error.

Now I want to use this in the workflow actions rules. What do I need to do? I chose the new rule to set it in the workflow rules area in the standard values section of the item, but when I execute the command in the workflow, it just doesn't run... what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Our team works with StandardValidator as the base for any field validation we are doing, such as writing an AlphanumericValidator that will ensure a text field value is, well, alpha-numeric.

I'm not sure what you are intending to do with the language versions, but I know we were running some workflow actions to check if an Item had a version in another language to inform the user of the current state of translation.  When an Approve action took place in a certain step, prior to final, we added a workflow action to kick off our code. Rather than using a validator, we actually implemented and registered an event handler.  It looked something like this:

```
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
{
    Item dataItemCurrentLanguage = args.DataItem;
    Item dataItemOtherLanguage = GetItemInOtherLanguage(dataItemCurrentLanguage);

    if (dataItemOtherLanguage != null && dataItemOtherLanguage.Versions.Count > 0)
    {
        //Insert what you want to check for here
        if(isGood)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else
        {
            Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Something bad!");
            args.AbortPipeline();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I think this would suffice for my function as well. I'm trying to check when an item goes into the final workflow state, before going there, that they have at least two different language versions... is this possible this way? if so, can you share more details?

Comment: Hey M.R, the AbortPipeline call is probably what you want to look into for stopping the flow to the final state.  The line above that is how you would inform the user of the information.

At that point, all you need to do is figure out your if/else logic to get you there.  The sample I provided above was meant for checking a bilingual site had both languages.  If you have more than 2 languages, you'll need to call GetItem in each of your languages, and check each one for the Versions count.  Then, if you don't find 2 language versions, abort with message.